# common lisp "overloading" built-in functions in a portable and efficient way?

Tags: math, coding-style, common-lisp, overloading

For example if I want to define new arithmetic operations for vectors or quaternions etc.
I did something like `(defun v+ (&rest vectors) ...)`.

Is there a good way to overload the normal `+`? (I only know shadowing-import, which seems not a good solution)

And if I use `+`, it would take more time to determine the type of operation.

Is it the best, not to overload, and use different function names and define a new function only if really needed?

Comment: Portably, only with another `+` symbol, as [redefining Common Lisp symbols is not conforming](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_abab.htm).  Even if you try to do it non-portably, you'll face either deoptimization or code walking (or environment inspection), because `cl:+` may have a compiler macro or some internal compiler construct that allows it to generate faster compiled code according to declared types.

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want to do is define a package (let's call it `my-math`), in which you define a symbol `my-math:+` that does whatever dispatching you need.

Alternatively, define `my-math:+` such that it is effectively `(reduce #'my-math:binary+ args)` and then define `my-math:binary+` as a generic function, which you can then hang specific methods on.

This still requires a bit of extra discipline when writing the package definition(s) relying on `my-math`, as you need to take pains to make sure that your unadorned `+` is from `my-math`, not `cl` and it may well make the code harder to read for another person.